# Bijection between a Hilbert and a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces

I am working on a question where I have to show that for a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$, and closed linear subspace $Y \subset \mathscr{H}$, $\mathscr{H}/Y$ is a Hilbert space, isomorphic to $Y^{\bot}$.

I have already shown that $\mathscr{H}/Y$ is a Banach space, and I have defined a map $T: Y^{\bot} \to \mathscr{H}/Y : x \to [x]$. I have shown that $T$ is linear and bijective.

However, I have failed to come up with an inner product on $\mathscr{H}/Y$. Now I was wondering: can I define the inner product $([x],[y])$ on $\mathscr{H}/Y$ to be the same as the inner product between the originals $(x,y)$ in the space $Y^{\bot}$? I thought so, but I have no idea how to prove it... Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the fact that
$$\mathscr{H} = Y \oplus Y^{\bot}$$
as vector spaces. So, if you want to define an inner product on $\mathscr{H}/Y \cong Y^{\bot}$ simply consider the inner product on $Y^{\bot}$. Precisely define
$$([x],[y]) = (\pi(x), \pi(y))$$
where $\pi:\mathscr{H} = Y \oplus Y^{\bot} \longrightarrow Y^{\bot}$ is the projection on the second coordinate, and show that it is well defined.

Comment: Thank you so much! So if I understand correctly, I need to show that for $a, a' \in [a]$ and $b, b' \in [b]$, the inner products $(a,b) = (a',b')$ ?

Comment: Or would showing that $\pi$ is injective be enough?

Comment: No: this is not true. You need to kill at all vectors the component belonging to $Y$. For example, you want that $([v],[v])=0$ in hte case that $v \in Y$, though you have $(v,v) \ge 0$.

Comment: No: $\pi$ is not injective.

Comment: I see your point :)